# Loading large data in an EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, parquet, pyarrow

I want to do modelling of data using Deep-Learning so I tried to load data in an EC2 instance(p2.8xlarge) from data stored in s3 i.e in parquet format the size of parquet folder in s3 is 9 GB, i am using pyarrow for loading the parquet data from s3 but it is taking around 3 hour to load that data and i would like to reduce it in between 10-15 min to an hour.
Any help would be really appreciated.Thanks

Comment: is the instance and s3 are in the same region? and which instance type you are using?

Comment: Yes they are in same region,the parquet size is compressed size when it is decompressed it is more than 50 GB,the instance type i am using is p2.8xlarge

Comment: your current instance bandwidth is `10GB` if you need high network performance then you need network optmized instance.

Comment: EC2 to S3 – Traffic to and from Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) can now take advantage of up to 25 Gbps of bandwidth. Previously, traffic of this type had access to 5 Gbps of bandwidth. This will be of benefit to applications that access large amounts of data in S3 or that make use of S3 for backup and restore.https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/the-floodgates-are-open-increased-network-bandwidth-for-ec2-instances/

Comment: Thanks so if i use network optimized instances i would be able to get data in limited time,can you suggest some network optimized instances,it would really help a lot.

Comment: let me post the answer how to work with your existing instance and network optmized instance will help.

Comment: Yeah but it would be very helpful if it is budget friendly and as well good for Deep learning modelling a because it need high computation

Comment: did this help to resolve the issue?

Comment: I just have some questions like i am using p2.8xlarge which is 10 GiB network bandwidth and the data that i have is around 80-90 GB isn't it should be fast enough to get it done in an hour atleast

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199829/discussion-between-adiii-and-rahul-vishwakarma).

Answer (score 0):

The first takeaway from this is that regions and connectivity matter. Obviously, if you’re moving data within AWS via an EC2 instance, such as off of an EBS volume, you’re better off if your EC2 instance and S3 region correspond. More surprisingly, even when moving data within the same region, Oregon (a newer region) comes in faster than Virginia

Secondly, instance types matter. If you’re using EC2 servers, some instance types have higher bandwidth network connectivity than others. You can see this if you sort by “Network Performance” on the excellent ec2instances.info list.

so You have to option to increase this speed.

- Enabled Enhanced Networking in your current instance and check the performance
- Used Network optimized instance that will provide high network bandwidth

**[Enhanced Networking on Linux:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html)**

First, try to enable Enhanced networking in your current instance and check performance if its improve then well if not then go for the next step.

> Enhanced networking uses the single root I/O virtualization (SR-IOV) to
>   provide **high-performance networking capabilities** on supported instance
>   types. SR-IOV is a method of device virtualization that provides
>   higher I/O performance and lower CPU utilization when compared to
>   traditional virtualized network interfaces

You can check for first for support if your current instance support that. You can check the article for support

[enable enhanced-networking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html)

**EC2 to S3** –

> Traffic to and from Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) can now take
>   advantage of up to 25 Gbps of bandwidth. Previously, traffic of this
>   type had access to 5 Gbps of bandwidth. This will be of benefit to
>   applications that access large amounts of data in S3 or that make use
>   of S3 for backup and restore.

[The-floodgates-are-open-increased-network-bandwidth-for-ec2-instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/the-floodgates-are-open-increased-network-bandwidth-for-ec2-instances/)

**Optimizing Network Intensive Workloads on Amazon EC2 A1 Instances**

> The [A1 instances are powered](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/a1/) by our internally developed
>   Arm-based AWS Graviton processors and are up to 45% less expensive
>   than other instance types with the same number of vCPUs and DRAM.
>   These instances are based on the AWS Nitro System, and offer
>   enhanced-networking of up to 10 Gbps with Elastic Network Adapters
>   (ENA).

[optimizing-network-intensive-workloads-on-amazon-ec2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/optimizing-network-intensive-workloads-on-amazon-ec2-a1-instances/)
 or
[i3en-of-i-o-optimized-ec2-instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-the-next-generation-i3en-of-i-o-optimized-ec2-instances/)

You can further explore these two articles which will help you to how to make s3 transfer to ec2 faster.

[/network-performance-within-amazon-ec2-and-to-amazon-s3](https://www.flexera.com/blog/cloud/2007/10/network-performance-within-amazon-ec2-and-to-amazon-s3/)

[10-things-might-not-know-using-s3](https://www.sumologic.com/insight/10-things-might-not-know-using-s3/)